# Making a HTTP POST request to a website with reCaptcha

Tags: forms, http, post, captcha, cross-site

I want to post to a form on another website that has a reCaptcha. Is there a way that I can fill out that reCaptcha on my website so that I can successfully make the HTTP POST request to the other website? Or does the reCaptcha have to be done on the website I'm trying to make a HTTP POST request to?

Comment: So you're trying to implement a spam bot? ;)

Comment: @PoByBolek I never said I wanted to bypass the captcha, I said I wanted to be able to enter the captcha on my site and use that captcha to post to the form on another site.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, there is a website A which has a form, protecting by a captcha challenge. And you have a website B, where you want to display the captcha challenge from website A. Thus the user of website B can solve the captcha challenge from website A and submit the solution along with some other information to website B. Then the server of website B can send HTTP POST request to website A?

Comment: @RandyTek - Can what you described be done?